# Replace string prefix in list of strings based on unicode code (ascii value) from another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, ascii

I have two lists like:

```
a = ['119', '111', '111', '108', '105', '97', '111']

b = ['119esi', '111dl', '111lw', '108dvei', '105n', '97n', '111ka']
```

The `a` list is representation of letter in ascii format but string. How can I merge them in a way that I get *"cohesive"* sentence.

In other words: `119` in ascii is a `'w'` so merge them so that the `b[0]` is `"wesi"` now, instead of `"119esi"`.

My desired output list is:

```
['wesi', 'odl', 'olw', 'ldvei', 'in', 'an', 'oka']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = ['119', '111', '111', '108', '105', '97', '111']
b = ['119esi', '111dl', '111lw', '108dvei', '105n', '97n', '111ka']

result = []

for ax, bx in zip(a, b):
    assert bx.startswith(ax)
    rest = bx[len(ax):]
    letter = chr(int(ax))
    result.append(letter + rest)

print(result)
# ['wesi', 'odl', 'olw', 'ldvei', 'in', 'an', 'oka']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`chr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr) in a *list comprehension* with [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) as:

```
>>> a = ['119', '111', '111', '108', '105', '97', '111']
>>> b = ['119esi', '111dl', '111lw', '108dvei', '105n', '97n', '111ka']

>>> [chr(int(i))+j[len(i):] if j.startswith(i) else j for i, j in zip(a, b)]
['wesi', 'odl', 'olw', 'ldvei', 'in', 'an', 'oka']
```

Here I am also checking whether your string in `b` starts with string in `a`.

If that's not a valid case for you, and it is fine to assume that string in `b` will always starts with string in `a`, you can further simplify it by skipping `if` condition as:

```
>>> [chr(int(i))+j[len(i):] for i, j in zip(a, b)]
['wesi', 'odl', 'olw', 'ldvei', 'in', 'an', 'oka']
```

Answer (score -1):

**Here is the program:-**

```
a = ['119', '111', '111', '108', '105', '97', '111']
b = ['esi', 'dl', 'lw', 'dvei', 'n', 'n', 'ka']
final = []
for x,y in zip(a,b):
   z = chr(int(x))+y
   final.append(z)
print(final)
```

This should be the solution but i am not 100% sure what your question is